# Put many resources and paths under subdomain (Rails Routes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain, rails-routing

I'd like to forward a bunch of stuff to a subdomain in my rails applications (including nested resources), without going through all my views to update all the `link_to _path` links. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

So far I have the following. Problem is, I can access everything either with or without the subdomain, without being redirect once I enter or leave a resource that should be on the subdomain. E.g. `example.com/apps` is the same as `connect.example.com/apps`, and the site root can either be `example.com` or `connect.example.com`

```
scope '/' do
 with_options :conditions => {:subdomain => 'connect'} do |site|

  site.resources :contracts
  site.resources :bills
  site.resources :feedbacks
  site.resources :newsletters
  site.resources :contacts
  site.resources :apps do
    site.resources :elements, controller: 'apps/elements' do
      site.resources :features, except: [:index], controller: 'apps/elements/features' do
        member do
          site.post 'complete'
        end
      end
    end
    site.resources :comments, controller: 'comments'
    site.resources :bills, controller: 'bills'
    site.resources :contracts, controller: 'contracts'

    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT 2**

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
     r307 %r{/apps/(.*)}, 'http://connect.localhost:3000/apps/$1'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite will let you do just this.  It's web server agnostic so it won't matter that you're on heroku.

eg.

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r307 %r{/apps/(.*)}, 'http://connect.example.com/apps/$1'
end
```

will issue a redirect for requests for /apps/ to go to connect.example.com/apps/

Comment: looks cool! any documentation for doing something like what I'm trying to do? I'm afraid I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in the read me

Comment: i put in an example, you can also add :host if you only want the redirect to happen on one of the subdomains

Comment: something got all messed up man. Now my localhost gets redirected to my production site or `example.com`. Check the edit.

Comment: The edit doesn't have example.com in it? It's really hard to help you without knowing exactly what steps you are doing and what is happening.  Try answering 
1) where you are testing (dev/staging/prod) 
2) what you have done 
3) what you expect to happen 
4) what is happening

Comment: Exactly, thats why I don't know where `example.com` is coming from. 1) dev (localhost), 2) only the code above 3) add the subdomain `connect` to all paths starting with `apps/` 4) on google chrome: a redirect loop when going to `connect.localhost/apps/1`, but `connect.local/apps` working as before (in the original question) and getting redirected to my production site from `localhost/anything`

Comment: just change it to ```r307 %r{/apps/(.*)}, 'http://connect.localhost:3000/apps/$1', host: 'localhost'```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83592/discussion-between-anko-and-nickdb93).